# Why does my short code get executed before other content?

Tags: theme-development, templates, shortcode

I have the following text in a page. As you can see my shortcode is right at the bottom but somehow when the code runs, the out put of my shortcode is inserted at the top of the page instead of following its preceding content.

```
<img class="alignnone" title="title_enquires" src="http://localhost/barcelona/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/title_enquires.jpg" alt="" width="589" height="77" />
<img class="alignnone" title="contact_map" src="http://localhost/barcelona/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/contact_map.jpg" alt="" width="555" height="222" />

[barcelona_address]
```

here is my short code registration inside the function.php file:

```
<?php
add_shortcode( 'barcelona_address', 'barcelona_shortcode_handler' );

function barcelona_address_func()
{
    print "<p>sdsdsds</p>";
}

function barcelona_shortcode_handler( $atts, $content=null, $code="" ) 
{
   if (function_exists($code . "_func"))
   {
       call_user_func($code . "_func", $atts);
   }
}
?>
```

and the result is:

```
<p>sdsdsds</p>
<img class="alignnone" title="title_enquires" src="http://localhost/barcelona/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/title_enquires.jpg" alt="" width="589" height="77" />
<img class="alignnone" title="contact_map" src="http://localhost/barcelona/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/contact_map.jpg" alt="" width="555" height="222" />
```

Comment: Change print to return

Comment: @Bainternet why did you not post that as an *answer*? :)

Comment: @Am01 be sure to mark Bainternet's answer as accepted!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The result of a shortcode appear BEFORE page content](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45378/the-result-of-a-shortcode-appear-before-page-content)

Answer (score 10):

By popular demand:

The solution is simply to replace `print` to `return` . Shortcodes should always return the value instead of printing or echoing it out.

Comment: And the symptom of this mistake is exactly what the OP observed: shortcode content being output before/at the beginning of `the_content()`.

Comment: face the same problem and solved by using return to the variable.