# The result of a shortcode appear BEFORE page content

Tags: shortcode

I have a page, with a shortcode that get all the post from a categorie and put after the content of the page. For no apparent reason, the result of a WP_Query() in the shortcode APPEAR ALWAYS at the top of the page. If i put the shortcode a the top OR at the bottom, the post (3 of them) appear before the content of the page...

on that one, i have NO IDEA why... shortcode is at the en of the page

---

after the comment i post the code the ECHO... this is the problem ?.. i to solve it ?

```
//Add a ShorCode to get a page/post content
add_shortcode ('post_cat2','get_post_cat2');
   function get_post_cat2 ($att) {

       $mypost = array();

       $args = array( 'category' => 36 );
       $myposts = get_posts( $args );

       foreach( $myposts as $post ) :   setup_postdata($post);
       $mypost .= the_title();
       endforeach;
       return $mypost;

   }
```

Comment: You're probably `echo`ing the content. Try `return`ing it.

Comment: yep i echo, can you explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[codex the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

replace this

```
$mypost .= the_title();
```

with

```
$mypost .= the_title('','',false);
```

Comment: +1. Or use `get_the_title()`. Either way: the issue is that `the_title()` **echoes** rather than **returns** its output, causing the shortcode output to print prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

I guessed it! Read the first paragraph of [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output). Try it. I'm sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: ok now the question with something like that :     $query = new WP_Query( 'p=1157' );
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
     
  the_content();

Comment: the_content(); echo... hot to return a value...???????

Comment: return `get_the_content()`.