# Shortcode always displaying at the top of the page

Tags: shortcode

I'm using a shortcode to pull in different loops via the loops-name.php. For some reason it is always at the top of the page. I googled it and using echo instead of return causes that problem but with my code I am not using echo. Here's the shortcode:

```
// setup the shortcode for use
function friendly_loop_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
'category' => '',
'module' => ''
), $atts ) );

include(locate_template('loop-'.$module.'.php'));
 }
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Shortcode for including a file? I find it a little odd.

Comment: 'with my code I am not using echo' - are the *loop-module.php* files echoing or returning their output?

Comment: Not at the moment - the file just has a paragraph tag with "test" written into it so I can see how it works.

Comment: use `get_template_part('loop',$module)` instead, it's prettier, quicker to type, supports parent/child themes, and it's the recommended method of including templates in wordpress ( yes locate_template may do some of those things but look how much less readable it is!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The result of a shortcode appear BEFORE page content](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45378/the-result-of-a-shortcode-appear-before-page-content)

Comment: I originally tried it with get_template_part but, if my memory serves me correctly, I couldn't pass my category variable to it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can buffer the output like this:

```
ob_start();
include(locate_template('loop-'.$module.'.php'));
return ob_get_clean();
```

EDIT. I tried this, worked fine.

```
function friendly_loop_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
         'category' => '',
         'module' => ''
     ), $atts ) );

     ob_start();
     include(locate_template('loop-'.$module.'.php'));
     $output = ob_get_clean();
     //print $output; // debug
     return $output;
}

if (!is_admin()) {
     add_shortcode('test', 'friendly_loop_shortcode' );
}
```

Comment: [Do not use output buffering](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41014/73) if there are other ways.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.

Comment: what went wrong? I tried and updated the answer

Answer (score 12):

Your included file is essentially echo-ing HTML. For instance

```
<?php
 //Some PHP
 echo 'test';
 //Some more PHP
 ?>
```

Is the same as

```
<?php
 //Some PHP 
 ?>
 test
<?php
 //Some more PHP
 ?>
```

Both get printed immediately rather than returned. Since its printed it appears before the page content. You need to *return* something for it be included in the content.

As @RutwickGangurde pointed out - it's unusual to include a template file in a shortcode.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. So I need to put the whole thing into a variable and return it? As for including a template file - well I want to make it as easy as possible for the theme users to customise the theme and having a huge shortcode file nested away from the root theme dir is not really ideal for them.

Comment: See @offroff's answer - that should work

Comment: "*well I want to make it as easy as possible for the theme users to customise the theme*" - Just how many abstraction layers are necessary? You've got a custom template file inside of a shortcode. I don't see how that makes things any easier for users. If you want to provide the ability to add static content to all posts, just define a `dynamic_sidebar()` inside the Loop, and let users add Widgets.

Comment: Most of the theme users will not appreciate having to trawl through a massive shortcode file to change a simple css class on the frontend. If I break up everything using the standard loop-name.php system then it's a lot faster for them to find what they need. Not ideal but I've got to keep them happy ;)

Comment: Very well explained;

Comment: This is the correct answer, because the cause of the problem was an indirect "echo" of the HTML, instead of building the HTML in a variable and "return" it at the end of function. In WordPress documentation, you can find this warning: *** Remember to use return and not echo - anything that is echoed will be output to the browser, but it won't appear in the correct place on the page.***