# shortcodes displaying outside of content area with echo statement, not what I wanted

Tags: plugins, shortcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcode always displaying at the top of the page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48491/shortcode-always-displaying-at-the-top-of-the-page)

I have my shortcode system set up fairly normally, like so:

```
//[carouselle]
function carouselle_func( $atts ){
 return "foo and bar";
}

add_shortcode( 'carouselle', 'carouselle_func' );
```

But when I do the same thing but with an echo statement instead of a return...

```
//[carouselle]
function carouselle_func( $atts ){
 echo "foo and bar";
}

add_shortcode( 'carouselle', 'carouselle_func' );
```

it displays "foo and bar" **inside the post** *and* also *immediately the body tag*.

[image: the echo statement]

I checked my header and I'm not calling the_content anywhere near there. So, is this because I'm doing an echo? I was hoping to eventualy do something like this:

```
//[carouselle]
function carouselle_func( $atts ){
 ?> 
 <h1>Some HTML Stuff</h1>
 <?php 
}

add_shortcode( 'carouselle', 'carouselle_func' );
```

But when this code executes, what happens is

## Some HTML stuff

gets displayed near the top of my theme and also in the content of the post. Bizarre, or is this not even allowed?

Comment: **Please** use the search before you post. And never use just the DOM view to see what's going on, view the real source instead.

Answer (score 7):

Shortcode functions are supposed to "return" the value, not echo it:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

```
//[carouselle]
function carouselle_func( $atts ){
 return "<h1>Some HTML Stuff</h1>";
}
add_shortcode( 'carouselle', 'carouselle_func' );
```