# shortcode outputs first before the page content

Tags: shortcode, plugin-wp-e-commerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcode always displaying at the top of the page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48491/shortcode-always-displaying-at-the-top-of-the-page)

I have a wordpress site with wp e-commerce plugin and gold cart plugin.

I have created a worpdress page with following:

———————————————–

some text some details about the page

[shortcode]

———————————————–

I have 2 different div blocks and shortcode is after the page content. But when the page renders the shortcode outputs first before the page content.

Can anyone help me to output the page content first and then the shortcode?

Thanks in advance for help.

Jaspal Singh aka jsxtech

Comment: please post more details such as what shortcode you are using, and if this is coming from the plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you've echoed the result of shortcode callback function rather than returning them. Please check here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

> Shortcodes are written by providing a handler function. Shortcode
>   handlers are broadly similar to WordPress filters: they accept
>   parameters (attributes) and return a result (the shortcode output).

you need to return the output that will be added to your content. if you echo them, it will be printed before the content.

if this is the not problem, please put the codes so that we can see what is the error.