# Shortcode Not displayed at the Right Place

Tags: posts, shortcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcode always displaying at the top of the page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48491/shortcode-always-displaying-at-the-top-of-the-page)

I am using custom shortcode to show some message at the end of the post. I am finding it hard to do so because it shows up at the top of the post. Here is my code.

I am placing the shortcode at the end of the post but the message appears at the top of the post.

What should I do to fix this?

```
function hello_kitty(){
if ( is_single() ){
    echo 'This is hello Kitty message';
}

}
add_shortcode('hellokitty',hello_kitty);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcodes are supposed to return your html, not echo it.

Make sure you check the documentation on the Shortcodes API
http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API