# Shortcode for output of wp_get_archives displays at top of post

Tags: shortcode, wp-get-archives

Why does the output of this function

```
// One Recent Post
function most_recent_post_shortcode() {
    return wp_get_archives( 'type=postbypost&limit=1&format=custom');
}
add_shortcode( 'recent-post', 'most_recent_post_shortcode' );
```

and shortcode `[recent-post]` show the output at the top of a post rather than in the body of the post where the shortcode is?

Is there a better way to use a shortcode and wp_get_archives (or other function) to display the title and link of a recent post?

It seems to have something to do with this question: [The result of a shortcode appear BEFORE page content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45378/the-result-of-a-shortcode-appear-before-page-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default of the `echo` argument is `true` for [`wp_get_archives()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives). I think this would fix it:

```
// One Recent Post
function most_recent_post_shortcode() {
    return wp_get_archives( 'type=postbypost&limit=1&format=custom&echo=0');
}
add_shortcode( 'recent-post', 'most_recent_post_shortcode' );
```

UPDATE:
Previously: echo=false
Now: echo=0

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't want to work....

Comment: Someone didn't read the Codex, and that person is me. It is an echo/return issue, I just didn't give echo the right value. Check the update.