# Shortcode displaying at the top of the page

Tags: php, shortcode, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The result of a shortcode appear BEFORE page content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45378/the-result-of-a-shortcode-appear-before-page-content)
>   [short code output too early](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47062/short-code-output-too-early)

I got this shortcode for display my blog posts on my page, but the EXCERPT and the COMMENTS are displaying on the top of my page. Anyone has any ideia why is doing that?

```
    /// Recent Blog Posts
add_shortcode('recent_blog_posts', 'shortcode_recent_blog_posts');

    function shortcode_recent_blog_posts($atts) {

            $str = '';
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
            $postslist = get_posts( $args );

            foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
                $str .= '<div id ="article-section-box2" class="span3">';
                                $str .= '<div id= "image1" class="image-arcticle">';     
                                $str .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '');
                                $str .= '</div>'; 

                                $str .='<p class ="orange16-no-bold">'.get_the_title($post->ID,'').'</p>';
                                $str .='<p class="date">13 Feb 2012 - <h6 class="orange-title">'.comments_popup_link('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments').';</h6></p>';
                                $str .='<p class="article_text">'.the_excerpt("child_of=8d").'</p>';
                                $str .='</div>';
            endforeach; 

            return $str;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the function `the_exerpt()`, replace this with `get_the_excerpt()`.
I don't know for sure, but you might need to use `apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt())` to maintain the formatting in wich `the_excerpt()` is returned.

Try to use `get_comment_reply_link` instead of `comments_popup_link`.

both functions `the_excerpt()` and `comment_popup_link()` won't return values, but **print** it, wich cause te content to be displayed at the top op the page.